# Sum of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{4^{(n/3)+1}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{4^{(n/3)+1}}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

geometric sequence with $$q=\frac{1}{4^{\frac{1}{3}}}\\$$
$$\frac{1}{4^{1}}+\frac{1}{4^{\frac{4}{3}}}++\frac{1}{4^{\frac{7}{3}}}++\frac{1}{4^{\frac{10}{3}}}+ ...\\=\frac{a_{1}}{1-q}=\\=\frac{\frac{1}{4^{1}}}{1-\frac{1}{4^{\frac{1}{3}}}}=\\$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Recall that $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^n =\frac{1}{1-r},\quad |r|<1.$$
Here $\displaystyle r=\frac{1}{4^{1/3}}$.

Answer (score 0):

prove by induction that for the definite sum holds
$\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{1}{4^{\frac{n}{3}+1}}=-1/12\, \left( {2}^{2/3}+2\,\sqrt [3]{2}+4 \right)  \left(  \left( 1/2
\,\sqrt [3]{2} \right) ^{m+1}-1 \right) 
$